# Exchange Realtime Logs? (Like tail on Linux)

Tags: exchange

Is there a way to monitor the exchange logs in realtime like using 'tail -f /var/log/mail.log' in linux?  The GUI tools for exchange under SBS 2008 suck for looking at what's going on in realtime.

Comment: What specifically are you after in real time that can't wait a day to analyse the whole tracking log?

Comment: It's about troubleshooting mail delivery problems with a host without me constantly having to hit 'go back' in the Message Tracking Wizard, followed by scrolling down and then clicking 'next' and waiting 10 seconds for Exchange to re-search through it's database.

Comment: Not that I think it will be much quicker, but have you tried with the Exchange Management Shell? Something like **Get-MessageTrackingLog -Eventid FAIL** or **Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients "recipient1","recipient2","etc"** might to do the trick. *(Warning: that was off the top of my head, so might fail on syntax)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange does not generate that kind of log. The closest it gets is deep in the message tree.

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\Logs\MessageTracking

As I said, that's not directly equivalent to /var/log/mail.log, but it is the store that Message Tracking sorts through.

Comment: This is why I love postfix (and to a slightly lesser extent every other mail server on Linux):  tail -f /var/log/mail.log

Comment: In addition, the log populated with a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Which logs specifically are you after? There are connectivity logs, message tracking logs, and protocol logs.

Answer (score -1):

The "get-content" powershell command can be used:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jessicadeen/microsoft/want-something-equivalent-to-the-linux-tail-command-but-for-windows-use-powershell/

Comment: This is a questions and answers site, not a link collection. Please include relevant content in your answer, not just a link to where the content may be as external links can go dead / be removed at any time. The link is nice to have in addition for reference or for further information. For more tips, see [about] and [answer].